# Key mappings in Linux

Tags: linux, osx, keyboard, keyboard-layout

What do people mean when they point out that the "keys are not properly mapped" in a Linux installation when working on the command line?

Isn't the default installation OK? What extra/specific mappings are needed?

I also was told that for my Mac where my <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys do not do what I expected.

Answer (score 7):

#### scancodes & keycodes

In general when someone says this they mean that the function labeled on a key does not match what "code" that key is sending to the Linux kernel when it's pressed. You can think of it as the key is labeled <kbd>Home</kbd> but the kernel is being sent the "code" for the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key.

At a much lower level part of what's really going on is that each key is assigned a scancode.

*excerpt from [scancode wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scancode)*

> A scancode (or scan code) is the data that most computer keyboards
> send to a computer to report which keys have been pressed. A number,
> or sequence of numbers, is assigned to each key on the keyboard.

These scancodes get mapped into keycodes by the Linux kernel. It's these keycodes which are usually communicated to the applications. Here's another [scancode resource](http://www.quadibloc.com/comp/scan.htm) if you'd like further details.

**NOTE:** this is an over simplification but I'm trying to just give you a general understanding of this layer. The key takeaway is that keys get pressed, scancodes are generated, Linux kernel sees these scancodes and emits keycodes.

#### setkeycodes

You can change the scancode keycode mapping using a tool `setkeycodes`:

> `setkeycodes scancode keycode ...`
>
> The  setkeycodes  command  reads  its  arguments two at a time, each
> pair of arguments consisting of a scancode (given in hexadecimal) and a
> keycode (given in decimal). For each such pair, it tells the kernel
> keyboard driver to map the  specified scancode to the specified keycode.

The keycode mapping is kept in keymap files. On my Fedora system my U.S. keymap file was located here, `/lib/kbd/keymaps/i386/qwerty/us.map.gz`. I found it by sleuthing a bit with this command:

```
$ locate map.gz|grep us
/lib/kbd/keymaps/amiga/amiga-us.map.gz
/lib/kbd/keymaps/atari/atari-us.map.gz
/lib/kbd/keymaps/i386/qwerty/br-latin1-us.map.gz
/lib/kbd/keymaps/i386/qwerty/is-latin1-us.map.gz
/lib/kbd/keymaps/i386/qwerty/us-acentos.map.gz
/lib/kbd/keymaps/i386/qwerty/us.map.gz
/lib/kbd/keymaps/i386/qwertz/cz-us-qwertz.map.gz
/lib/kbd/keymaps/mac/all/mac-us.map.gz
/lib/kbd/keymaps/sun/sunt5-cz-us.map.gz
/lib/kbd/keymaps/sun/sunt5-us-cz.map.gz
```

Notice these files are compressed (.gz) so you have to either unzip them (don't bother) or use `zcat` or `zless` to look through them:

```
$ zless /lib/kbd/keymaps/i386/qwerty/us.map.gz
# us.map
keymaps 0-2,4-6,8-9,12
alt_is_meta
include "qwerty-layout"
include "linux-with-alt-and-altgr"
include "compose.latin1"
include "euro1.map"
strings as usual

keycode   1 = Escape
keycode   2 = one              exclam
keycode   3 = two              at               at               nul              nul
keycode   4 = three            numbersign
        control keycode   4 = Escape
keycode   5 = four             dollar           dollar           Control_backslash
keycode   6 = five             percent

...
...

keycode  97 = Control
```

So if you wanted to change the "Control" key (keycode 97) and set it to the scancode for the "Left Control" key, (scancode 0x1d 0x9d), you'd use the following:

```
$ setkeycodes 1d9d 97 &
```

#### showkey

You can also see what keycode a key is mapped to using the command `showkey`:

```
$ sudo showkey -a

Press any keys - Ctrl-D will terminate this program

1    49 0061 0x31
2    50 0062 0x32
3    51 0063 0x33
a    97 0141 0x61
b    98 0142 0x62
c    99 0143 0x63
^[OH 27 0033 0x1b
     79 0117 0x4f
     72 0110 0x48
^D    4 0004 0x04
```

The "^[OH" is me pressing my <kbd>HOME</kbd> key.

**NOTE1:** When in `ascii' dump mode (`showkey -a`), showkey prints to the standard output the decimal, octal, and hexadecimal value(s) of the  key pressed, according to the present keymap.

Comment: [How do I find out the emitted keycode of Fn+F6?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125476/how-do-i-find-out-the-emitted-keycode-of-fnf6) if showkey and xev do not work?

Answer (score 1):

I use a MacBook Pro and don't have any problems with key mappings when I log into UNIX systems so the default settings are almost certainly fine and no mappings are needed. I regularly use Debian, Ubuntu, RedHat and Solaris 11.

However, what people mean when they say that is in **Terminal Preferences** under **Settings** in the **Keyboard** tab. You can edit your key mappings there.

The only change I've made is to enable *use option as meta*.

With regard to <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd>, I use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> for Home and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> for End instead because I don't like where Home and End keys are on keyboards. I've also changed my <kbd>caps lock</kbd> key into another <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key (in System Preferences under Keyboard) because that's the traditional location for a ctrl key, it's more comfortable and seriously, who uses caps lock?

Comment: In `vimrc` I `vmapped` `CTRL-c` to `y` so that I can copy blocks of text and `CTRL-p` to `P` so that I can paste it. This works in linux but in my Mac Book it does not. Seems like I can not use `CTRL` properly. Any idea why is this and how can I fix it?

Comment: @Jim either edit your original question or ask a new question for that.