# zsh: Where is the `key` -> `terminfo` dictionary defined

Tags: zsh, keyboard-shortcuts, zle

I'm learning `zsh` at the moment, and configuring my `~/.zshrc`. On the Archwiki, I found a [snippet to change the history searching behavior](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/zsh#History_search):

```
autoload -Uz up-line-or-beginning-search down-line-or-beginning-search
zle -N up-line-or-beginning-search
zle -N down-line-or-beginning-search

[[ -n "$key[Up]"   ]] && bindkey -- "$key[Up]"   up-line-or-beginning-search
[[ -n "$key[Down]" ]] && bindkey -- "$key[Down]" down-line-or-beginning-search
```

After scouring the `man` pages however, I cannot find any documentation on the `key` keyword or what parameters it can take. `grep`-ing for `man zshall | grep -i "key.*\["` does not show any more information, nor does the `man zshzle` entry for `bindkey`. The closest relevant match is the following from `man zshcontrib`:

```
...
source ${ZDOTDIR:-$HOME}/.zkbd/$TERM-$VENDOR-$OSTYPE
[[ -n ${key[Left]} ]] && bindkey "${key[Left]}" backward-char
[[ -n ${key[Right]} ]] && bindkey "${key[Right]}" forward-char
# etc.
...
```

I found more examples at [zshwiki](http://zshwiki.org/home/zle/bindkeys) and [an answer from @rayandrews on Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/117162/240807), although neither appear to be or claim to be the full list of parameters to `key`, nor describe where/how `key` is defined.

**Where can I learn more about `key[...]` and how to use it?**

Comment: The wiki shows an *example*, which is not in the zsh sources (though some packager may have added that).  For another example, see [zkbd](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/master/Functions/Misc/zkbd).

Comment: Yes the wiki is not official documentation. I did already try running `zkbd`, which created an `xterm-256color-:0` file for me. It doesn't contain any more info than I already had unfortunately, but I can add the contents to my post if you think it's helpful.

Comment: The wiki example shows how to assign terminfo capabilities to the key hash.  zsh has a list of the standard terminfo key-names (such as `kdch1`) and the example uses a more understandable *Delete*.  In regard to your question, the *parameter* to `key` is the user-assigned name.  Someone could define additional names, but there's no "full list".

Comment: It's possible that I may need to open another question to understand how this works. I can see that `key[...]` is just a dictionary for the more opaque `terminfo` parameters. But I have not defined this dictionary anywhere, so (in the Archwiki example) how does `$key[Up]` not throw an error? The `key` dictionary must exist somewhere on my machine, no?

Comment: A packager may have added it to the zsh initialization-scripts (different systems have different packages...).

Comment: I see. So I'd need to dig into the installer to figure it out? Yikes...

Comment: Probably (`pacman` should have something to list the contents of a package, and from that you could grep for things that would be in the hash, to see where `key` is populated).

Comment: Look at m recent answer, it may shed some light: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/379084/80886

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Debian, `/etc/zsh/zshrc` has:

```
    typeset -A key
    key=(
        BackSpace  "${terminfo[kbs]}"
        Home       "${terminfo[khome]}"
        End        "${terminfo[kend]}"
        Insert     "${terminfo[kich1]}"
        Delete     "${terminfo[kdch1]}"
        Up         "${terminfo[kcuu1]}"
        Down       "${terminfo[kcud1]}"
        Left       "${terminfo[kcub1]}"
        Right      "${terminfo[kcuf1]}"
        PageUp     "${terminfo[kpp]}"
        PageDown   "${terminfo[knp]}"
    )
```

It was added by [that commit](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/zsh/commit/cb9eb75f2bb6b038ce25b15383f0a32455f7b2a5) in `zsh` Debian package 5.0.0-1.

Possibly Arch copied that `zshrc` from Debian. In any case, that is not part of the upstream zsh distribution.

You can always look at the definition of the `$key` hash with:

```
typeset -p key | sed -n l
```

Or

```
printf '%q => %q\n' "${(@kv)key}"
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Can you give an example of what to substitute for `key` in `typeset -p key | sed -n l`, please? Everything I've tried returns the error "no such variable".

Comment: @iain, the question was _where is the $key hash documented_. The answer is it's not be cause `$key` is just a variable defined in the system's zshrc by some Linux distributions. Yours is not one of them, $key is not defined, it you want to bind some function keys to some actions, you can use the $terminfo hash directly or copy the definition of that $key hash into your .zshrc