# Disable Ctrl+C in GNU screen?

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

How can I disable the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> on GNU-screen? Actually I would have to get used to it, but I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> rather than <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> out of habit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now I've found the answer myself. The instructions

```
defscrollback 30000
bindkey "^C" echo 'Blocked. Please use [Ctrl]+[A] + [Ctrl]+[Enter] + [Y]'
bindkey "^D" echo 'Blocked. Please use [Ctrl]+[A] + [Ctrl]+[Enter] + [Y]'
bind "^M" quit
```

in the file

```
~/.screenrc
```

lead to the fact that C-c only executes the `echo` command, thus no longer sends an interrupt. Instead you can stop the screen with `^M` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. Because I use `bind` (unlike `bindkey`) you have to press C-a first. The confirmation prompt can be confirmed with <kbd>Y</kbd>. The advantage of this solution is that I don't have to change the actual Java or Python program. Please remember that running screen sessions must be restarted in order to read the new `~/.screenrc` file. (This path depends on the user, e.g. `/root/.screenrc` or `/home/user/.screenrc`.)

Helpful links:

- Docu: http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/screen_13.html
- Find your own key combination: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/116588/239596

Tested with

- Screen version 4.01.00devel (GNU) 2-May-06
- Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
- MobaXterm v10.9 Build 3656 (Windows)

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> sends the `INT` (interrupt) signal to the process currently in the foreground.  This is an important signal to be able to send, so the best thing would be to just learn not to press that key combination by mistake.

You *can* also remap that key combination so that you have another control sequence that sends the `INT` signal.  For example, you may make <kbd>Ctrl+G</kbd> do the same thing with the shell command

```
stty intr ^G
```

The <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> key combination will then just send a character with ASCII code 3.

Again, it would probably be less problematic to just learn to use <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> correctly.

Comment: Thank you. I'll take care of it. Unfortunately I can only use your command outside of screen. A Java or Python program runs inside. I have already pressed the wrong key combination so often that I have to do something. ;)

Comment: @uav Ah. If you are able to modify the code of the program, you could make it ignore the `INT` signal completely.

Comment: That is possible, but I have posted a more general answer. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid this issue in the first place by using logging as follows:

1. While creating the screen, use this command to generate a log file:

```
screen -L -Logfile file_name.log
```

2. Now, to check the screen, do not resume it; instead read the log file interactively, with *one* of these two commands:

```
tail -f -n 20 file_name.log
```

```
watch tail file_name.log
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well, just as I have the habit of pressing [Ctrl]+[C], I have the habit of going in with `screen -r`, so your solution is only something for disciplined people - who don't exist. ;) My point is not to avoid the error, but to prevent it. ;D