# Terminal skills: special keycodes for better typing. I can't find a list

Tags: shell, terminal, zsh, macos

I want to level up my terminal skills, specifically when entering commands, to improve my efficiency. For example, when typing a command, I want to delete a word to the left of the cursor, instead of pressing backspace 5 times.

I already know how this works: the terminal app can catch a keyboard shortcut, such as `Ctrl-backspace`, and send a special keycode to the shell. The shell has built in functionality for this type of editing, and it recognizes the keycode and does what we want. Did I explain it correctly?

[image: shortcut to keycode settings]

This works and is fantastic functionality, but where can I find a list of things that are possible? Just today I realized that `0x1f` means "undo". I never knew this was possible, and I love it! I want to see what else is possible, but I don't know what to search for! I tried for half an hour and gave up.

I am using Macos, the default Zsh 5.8 shell, and iTerm2 app.

Comment: You misunderstood the question, I don't want a list of TERMINAL app functionality, I want a list of SHELL functionality. I need to find a list where it says "0x1f means undo, 0x1b means delete word left, 0x7f means delete character".

Answer (score 4):

Those keyboard shortcuts are documented in your shell's manual. Since your shell is zsh, look at the chapter [“Zsh Line Editor”](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#Zsh-Line-Editor) in the manual, available locally with `man zshzle`.

Regarding the correspondence the key bindings involving Control and ESC and keyboard keys, see [key bindings table?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116562/key-bindings-table) and [How do keyboard input and text output work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116629/how-do-keyboard-input-and-text-output-work/116630#116630) for some background. Note in particular that you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> followed by a key to see what escape sequence it sends. On a Mac terminal, by default, the <kbd>Option</kbd> key sends ESC followed by what the key sends (usually).

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, the functionality I am describing is controlled through the command `bindkey`. Running bindkey without any options will print out the current bindings, here is an example:

```
"^@" set-mark-command
"^A" beginning-of-line
"^B" backward-char
"^D" delete-char-or-list
"^E" end-of-line
"^F" forward-char
"^G" send-break
"^H" backward-delete-char
"^I" expand-or-complete
"^J" accept-line
"^K" kill-line
...
```

Because I didn't know these are called "key bindings" I couldn't find the answer on google.

So now I have a list of what is possible, I just need to translate it to hex to make the answer truly useful to someone using iTerm2.

Comment: I presume that you know that ^A (control-A ) is hex 0x01, ^B is 0x02, and so on? Also that the tty driver will respond to certain keys before sending them to the shell - so run stty -a to see those settings.